# Making a control invisible when its out of bounds of a parent control? in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, canvas

I'm trying to put a bigger `MediaElement` into a smaller `Canvas` on WPF.

Lets say i'm putting 600x400 media into a 400x300 Canvas with `Canvas.Top = -50, Canvas.Left = -100`.

And i don't want the sides that are out of bounds to be displayed, in this case 50 pixels from top and bottom, 100 pixel from right and left of my media should be invisible.

How can i achieve this? Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for is called "Clipping".  You need to add a `RectangleGeometry` to the `Canvas.Clip` property:-

```
 <Canvas Width="400" Height="300">
     <Canvas.Clip>
         <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 400 300" />
     </Canvas.Clip>
     <!-- Your content here --->
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't find the right word for it, yes Clipping! thanks again!